# How to make a sliding tile menu screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, viewflipper

I'm working on an Android Picross puzzle game.

**Background info:** I would like to make a menu system that uses a series of rectangles or cards, I suppose. You'd swipe through the cards to decide on a difficulty level, then tap the card to enter a sub-menu.

The cards to the left and right of your current selected card will be visible from the sides, and they animate as you swipe along them, growing as they reach the middle of the screen (selected). Tapping the cards to the left and right will automatically animate and centre that card.

Tapping the open card (choosing "easy", for example), should animate outwards to fill the screen with the set of easy levels.

It's sort of hard to explain without pictures, so I've linked **some mockups in an imgur album [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkVO.jpg)**.

**Question:**
This is my first Android app and I'm not sure about all the different types of layouts and widgets available, and which to use. Would a ViewFlipper work, or is there some better way of accomplishing this?

I'm using a main activity, with a Material toolbar and navigation drawer, and fragments for swapping out the content.

My project is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/theRealPadster/simple-picross) in case that helps at all.

Comment: Use a Viewpager, it will automatically give you the sliding feature and along with that you can add animation on sliding.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner at android development as well. Hopefully I will be able to help you.

There two different layouts I would use. For the first, I believe your tiles are sliding from left to right / right to left? I would use a vertical Linear Layout.

If you use a linear layout, know that you will need to create an adapter to create the children objects for the Linearlayout [Something I have not done using something other than a textview within the linear layout]

For the second image, without scrolling I would use a GridLayout. If scrolling I would suggest a linear layout, horizontal.

The reason I do not suggest a GridLayout within a scrollview layout, is that it seems doing so has given my android devices performance issues.

There are several LinearLayout tutorials online.

Comment: For left to right why use a vertical layout? I'll take a look at adaptors, is that how I would get them to slide along? A GridLayout would be good for the second image. The main thing with that one was figuring out how to animate the card to expand and fill the screen.